# VS2010 MFC: Adding Standard File Toolbar w/o appWizard

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm deep into a MFC project that I originally didn't think needed a toolbar, so I didn't have the app wizard put it in. Now I'm regretting it and I need the default new file and save file toolbar items. I know I can create a toolbar from the resource view but I can't figure out how to get the default images for those items. I tried the import option under add resource, but the imported image gets placed in a separate BMP Resource, not my toolbar resource. How do I get the default toolbar images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to create a new empty project with a toolbar and to copy/paste from there all toolbar related code. Please let me know if you need farther assistance.

Comment: Copying the resource files was easy enough, but now I am realizing all the places in the view class and mainfrm class where toolbar objects functions are called. This is a little tedious, but it's time I learn underlying code instead of blindly relying on the auto-gen from wizards.

Comment: Glad you take it easily :-). Again, don't hesitate to ask if you are stuck with something.